# Is it possible to check if back-reference is not empty in GNU sed?

Tags: regex, sed

Let's say that I want to replace string `abc` with `klm` and `abcd` with `klmn`. One can do it like this: `echo -e "abc\nabcd" | sed -r '/d$/ s/abcd/klmn/ ; /d$/! s/abc/klm/'`. However, it made me wonder is it somehow possible to check if back-reference is not empty in GNU `sed`? For example, something like `echo -e "abc\nabcd" | sed -r 's/abc(d)?/klm(?(\1)n)/'` which would print the `n` **if** `\1` is not empty.

Comment: It might not be supported out of the box in `sed`, `perl` might

Comment: as far as I know, you cannot add conditional code in replacement section in `sed`, but you could do it with `perl`... also, you could use branching commands to shorten the sed command to `sed 's/abcd/klmn/; t; s/abc/klm/'`

Comment: Can you provide some details about the motivation - the 2 substitution that were listed seems straightforward and simple

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: NO.

Long Answer: for the above substitution to work, there should be extension to the 'REPLACEMENT' part of the 's' command. Unfortunately, it currently takes only back references, and case changing instructions (as GNU sed extension). No additional logic.

As a side note, even perl does not have simpler way to express the above substitution.

Comment: perl allows code in replacement section, so one of the ways to do it would be `printf 'abc\nabcd\n' | perl -pe 's/abc(d)?$/"klm" . ($1 && "n")/e'`

Comment: My comment was that the above code is more complex than the original 2 piece substitution included by the OP. Given `sed` limited logic (branches) hard to see how a generic logic will work.

Comment: @Sundeep : Was trying out something on that line! Not a Perl expert but doesn’t arithmetic evaluation mode /e support a literal string comparison and a string substitution? May be a ternary op?

Comment: @Inian not sure what you mean by arithmetic evaluation mode, the `e` modifier allows you to use any Perl code in the replacement section, output of which will be treated as replacement string.. you can use ternary operator `perl -pe 's/abc(d)?$/$1 ? "klmn" : "klm"/e'` or pretty much anything else..

Comment: @Sundeep : Makes sense! Thought the /e applied only to arithmetic operations on the captured group. Also I think you should post that as an answer. OP is looking for something similar with sed which doesn’t support it.